# height of input tag in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I have a div, which has an input and button tag. How can I make the height same as the height of the div?

I have tried the following code:

```
  <div class="input-area" style="border:1px solid;display:table;background:green;">
        <input type="text" style="border:none;display:table;float:left;background-color:red;" />
        <button>Search</button>
  </div>
```

Since I can't upload images till now, here is a link to it:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxCMhBQ7C3kLemVEemJYUldaZWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: **I have a div, which has an and ??**

Comment: Why `display:table`? `<div>` and `<table>` elements should be used for different purposes, if you need a table use a table (although you don't in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this. [Here are two](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/2MnL2/):

1. Give the `div` container a specific height, then give the `input`
   element a height of `100%`:

   ```
   <div class="input-area" style="height:50px;">
       <input type="text" style="height:100%;" />
   </div>
   ```
2. Position the `input` element absolutely, and the `div` container relatively, then use some more CSS to style it properly:

   ```
   <div class="input-area" style="position:relative;width:200px">
       <input type="text" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;right:50px;" />
   </div>
   ```

Also, move your CSS to an external file. Inline styles are annoying.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input height="pixels">
```

in pixels set your height as you want . Try it

Answer (score 1):

Text input is tricky because of the differences in browsers. I use the following in my CSS to ensure that all inputs have the same height:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 24px;
}
```